# How can I reset a text area input element?

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to figure out exactly how I can reset a textarea back to its original state with the placeholder text.
The best I have so far is the following;

```js
//Created ref to clear after keydown
  const inputRef = React.useRef(null);

  return (

      <Input
        ref={inputRef}
        as="textarea"
        placeholder="this text box should clear after an enter press"
        style={{ height: "300px" }}
        onKeyDown={(e) => {
          if (e.code === "Enter") {
            inputRef.current.value = "";
          }
        }}
      />
  );
}
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-knuth-4k4ys7?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) which would help to prevent adding a new character after populating your state data.

```
<Input
        ref={inputRef}
        as="textarea"
        placeholder="this text box should clear after an enter press"
        style={{ height: "300px" }}
        onKeyDown={(e) => {
          if (e.code === "Enter") {
            setData(inputRef.current.value);
            inputRef.current.value = "";
            //prevent adding a new character
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        }}
      />
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-herschel-wjzbrr)

Comment: Would you elaborate a bit on your answer ? I don't understand how preventing a new character being entered and having the element reset are related... 
(It does work though !)

Comment: @cassepipe onKeyDown happens before onChange. With e.preventDefault(), we're preventing onChange triggers after pressing `Enter`